# Check if double are given with a specific accuracy

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy, integer-arithmetic

I have a vector of `double`. Those numbers are given with a precision such as `0.001` meaning that the numbers are given with a thousandth of units accuracy. For example I'm expecting to have `123456789.012` but not `123456789.01231`. In practice, because of floating-point arithmetic the actual numbers are more like `123456789.01199999452` which is the valid and closest representation of `123456789.012`.

I'd like to robustly test if my numbers are actually given with the accuracy there are supposed to be. For example I'd like to warn if I have the `123456789.01231` which does not match with the accuracy `0.001`. Another valid option to me is to find the accuracy of a given number.

What I've done so far is to test if `(x - offset)/accuracy` is an integer. The offset protects against integer overflow. In practice, because of floating-point arithmetic, it cannot be an integer so I added an arbitrary threshold. It works but it is not a robust solution in my opinion.

```cpp
dx = (x[i]-offset)/accuracy;
ix = std::round(dx);
if (std::abs(dx - ix) > 1e-5)
  throw exception("...");
```

No string is involved in this process. The numbers come from binary files or from runtime computations. The accuracy is given by the user and the numbers are expected to be compliant with this accuracy. In my previous example of `123456789.012` I do know that this number does not actually exist but `123456789.01199999452` is valid because it is its best representation with `double`. But `123456789.01231` (actually `123456789.01230999827`) is not valid because it is not the best representation of the 3 digits rounded value.

Comment: Multiple by 1000 and check that fractional part is withing a threshold - for exaple add 0.001 and check that result is less than 0.01, not sure about actual values though.

Comment: Assuming that these numbers are "given" in the form of text to begin with, you can read strings and verify the format before converting.

Comment: @molbdnilo no string involved in the process.

Comment: What you want to do is against the nature of the floating point numbers. Not only the numbers are not accurately representable in floating point, the actual precision depends on the number magnitude. What you're looking for is likely a fixed point format designed to fit your purpose. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

Comment: @AndreySemashev it is not. I mean `123456789.01199999452` is the valid and closest representation of `123456789.012`. And it is not `123456789.01232`. This is what I want to test.

Comment: @JRR I'm not sure I understand the task you're solving. Do you mean that you preemptively know the "correct" values of the FP numbers? How do you know 123456789.01199999452 is correct and 123456789.01232 is not? From the FP representation point of view, they are not differentiated. Please, provide the criteria of "correctness" in the question.

Comment: In which "manner" are the numbers given? How do you know about the precision part?

Comment: @JRR I had the same doubts as Andrey.  How do you know what value is right and which is wrong?  Is there some "hand calculation" done that you are testing against?  Also, I rarely, if ever see these ad-hoc ways of beating floating point inaccuracies work 100% of the time.  Might as well just use a fixed-point library or similar.

Comment: @JRR Just in case if you want to check the mathematical error of computations, this is a quite different task than what you described. In this case you could decompose the FP numbers to sign, exponent and mantissa and test that sign, exponent and N most significant bits of mantissa are equal to the expected values. Here, N denotes the required accuracy.

Comment: Question edited to clarify why a number is better than another. Hope this help.

Comment: You can't determine which number is closest to 123456789.012 unless you have 123456789.012 to compare with, which you can't get.

Comment: If you round `123456789.01231` to 3 digits you get `123456789.01199999452` while the round of `123456789.01199999452` to 3 digits is `123456789.01199999452`. A robust rounding method should make the job no?

Comment: I'd have a look at the difference between x and std::nexttoward(x,0) and check whether it is smaller than 1/512. That way, you would know that even if the value isn't represented exactly, it is represented by the closest number the type can hold.

Comment: @UriRaz: That test tells you whether x is less than 2^43 in magnitude (assuming IEEE-754 binary64 is in use). That is not a useful test for OP’s problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to ensure that your numbers are as close as possible to a set of numbers, which are an [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) from 0 to infinity with common difference of the accuracy value. In this case, this is basically a [quantization task](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(signal_processing)) with further evaluation of the quantization error.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

bool is_number_accurate(double n, double accuracy)
{
    bool accurate = false;

    std::cout << "n: " << n << ", ";

    n = std::abs(n);
    if (n > accuracy)
    {
        // Epsilon to account for precision loss from the calculations below,
        // as well as floating point representation error.
        const double epsilon = 0.00001;

        // Remainder from quantizing n to accuracy precision
        // (i.e. quantization error)
        double rem = std::fmod(n, accuracy);

        // Normalize to 1.0. Here 0 means n exactly matches the quantized value,
        // and slightly greater than 0 means that n is slightly greater than the
        // quantized value.
        // Values close to 1.0 also mean n is close to match the quantized value,
        // but is slightly less than it.
        double error = rem / accuracy;
        std::cout << "error: " << error << ", ";

        accurate = error < epsilon || (error <= 1.0 && error > (1.0 - epsilon));
    }
    else
    {
        accurate = n == 0.0 || n == accuracy;
    }

    std::cout << "accurate: " << accurate << std::endl;

    return accurate;
}

int main()
{
    is_number_accurate(0.0, 0.001);
    is_number_accurate(0.0000000000001, 0.001);
    is_number_accurate(0.001, 0.001);
    is_number_accurate(0.01, 0.001);
    is_number_accurate(123456789.012, 0.001);
    is_number_accurate(123456789.0121, 0.001);
    is_number_accurate(123456789.0125, 0.001);
    is_number_accurate(123456789.0129, 0.001);
    is_number_accurate(123456789.013, 0.001);
    is_number_accurate(123456789.01231, 0.001);
}
```

The output is:

```
n: 0, accurate: 1
n: 1e-13, accurate: 0
n: 0.001, accurate: 1
n: 0.01, error: 0, accurate: 1
n: 1.23457e+08, error: 0.999992, accurate: 1
n: 1.23457e+08, error: 0.0999936, accurate: 0
n: 1.23457e+08, error: 0.5, accurate: 0
n: 1.23457e+08, error: 0.899992, accurate: 0
n: 1.23457e+08, error: 0.999994, accurate: 1
n: 1.23457e+08, error: 0.309996, accurate: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem stated in the question is suggestive of an attempt to use floating-point in ways it was not designed for, but there is insufficient information given to suggest alternatives. So, with some reluctance, here is a solution for the problem as stated.

```
/*  IsNearestValue(x, A) returns true iff x is the double number nearest to the
    nearest multiple of A', where A' is the unit fraction nearest A.  (All
    negative powers of 10, such as 10**-3, are unit fractions.)

    For example, IsNearestValue(x, .001) returns true iff x is the result of
    converting some number with three decimal digits after the decimal point
    to double.

    This routine presumes x/A <= 2**53.
*/
bool IsNearestValue(double x, double A)
{
    //  Calculate 1/A'.  The result has no rounding error.
    double reciprocal = std::round(1/A);

    /*  Find what multiple of A' x must be near.  This produces an exact
        result.  That is, t is an integer such that t * A' = x, with
        real-number arithmetic, not floating-point arithmetic.
    */
    double t = std::round(x * reciprocal);

    //  Calculate the double nearest t/A'.
    t /= reciprocal;

    //  Return true iff x is the double nearest t/A'.
    return x == t;
}
```

The concept here is pretty simple. First, we correct the problem that `A` is given as a `double`, but none of the desired numbers (.1, .01, .001) can be represented in a `double`. However, their reciprocals can, so we take the reciprocal and round to get exactly the reciprocal of the desired number.

Then we multiply `x` by the reciprocal and round to the nearest integer. Then we divide that integer by the reciprocal, and that gives us the `double` that `x` must be if it is indeed the `double` nearest some multiply of the desired `A`.

I am not sure the constraint *x*/*A* ≤ 2<sup>53</sup> is necessary, but I have not tried to prove it is not, so I am leaving that bound unless there is further request.